# i am experiencing an unusual behaviour in my html code. what may be the problem?

Tags: html

So i am editing a bootstrap template(it's a free template) for my project. I have removed the images and placed my own. but the problem is that my own image doesn't load, instead the previous background image is being displayed. How is this possible ? that image doesn't have existence and still it's appearing. Also previously i intended to do this

```
<a href="../index.php" class="btn btn-warning" role="button">Go Back</a>
```

but then I changed my mind and instead did this

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="history.go(-1);" role="button">Go Back </button>
```

the problem again is the same. the browser won't load the current code, instead it's loading previous code.
i did everything i could, i changed the browser, cleared cache and cookies, rewrote the codes saved it again and again...still won't get the desired result. what is the problem anyway ? i can't figure it out.

Comment: seems like its working

Comment: Sweet, going to post as an answer so you can accept :)

Comment: @Brad there you go. :) and thanks a  lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried clearing your chache? My advice would be to go into chrome dev tool and there is an option under the newtwork tab disable cache this will ensure you are always getting a fresh version when you have dev tool open.